# Python, Plotly, and Raspberry Pi [Errno 13]

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to follow the second code example shown by estromsnes at:
[How to create two y-axes streaming plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161244/how-to-create-two-y-axes-streaming-plotly)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import re
import sys
import time
import datetime
import plotly.plotly as py # plotly library
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter, Layout, Figure, Data, Stream, YAxis

# Plot.ly credentials and stream tokens
username                 = 'plotly_username'
api_key                  = 'plotly_api_key'
stream_token_temperature = 'stream_token_1'
stream_token_humidity    = 'stream_token_2'

py.sign_in(username, api_key)

trace_temperature = Scatter(
    x=[],
    y=[],
   stream=Stream(
        token=stream_token_temperature
    ),
    yaxis='y'
)

trace_humidity = Scatter(
    x=[],
    y=[],
    stream=Stream(
        token=stream_token_humidity
    ),
    yaxis='y2'
)

layout = Layout(
    title='Raspberry Pi - Temperature and humidity',
    yaxis=YAxis(
        title='Celcius'
    ),
    yaxis2=YAxis(
        title='%',
        side='right',
        overlaying="y"
    )
)

data = Data([trace_temperature, trace_humidity])
fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

print py.plot(fig, filename='Raspberry Pi - Temperature and humidity')

stream_temperature = py.Stream(stream_token_temperature)
stream_temperature.open()

stream_humidity = py.Stream(stream_token_humidity)
stream_humidity.open()

while(True):
  # Run the DHT program to get the humidity and temperature readings!
  output = subprocess.check_output(["./Adafruit_DHT", "2302", "17"]);
  print output

  # search for temperature printout
  matches = re.search("Temp =\s+([0-9.]+)", output)
  if (not matches):
        time.sleep(3)
        continue
  temp = float(matches.group(1))

  # search for humidity printout
  matches = re.search("Hum =\s+([0-9.]+)", output)
  if (not matches):
        time.sleep(3)
        continue
  humidity = float(matches.group(1))

  print "Temperature: %.1f C" % temp
  print "Humidity:    %.1f %%" % humidity

  # Append the data to the streams, including a timestamp
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  stream_temperature.write({'x': now, 'y': temp })
  stream_humidity.write({'x': now, 'y': humidity })

  # Wait 30 seconds before continuing
  time.sleep(30)

stream_temperature.close()
stream_humidity.close()
```

I am asking a new question because I could not do so on the original post.

My terminal's output from my Raspberry Pi Model B+ V1.2 states:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "plotly5.py", line 62, in <module>
  output = subprocess.check_output(["./Adafruit_DHT", "2302", "17"]);
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check output
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Is there a permissions setting I should change?
Should I change the ./Adafruit_DHT portion of:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["./Adafruit_DHT", "2302", "17"]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you just run that program from the shell? Does it need sudo permission?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try that in the Python 2.7.9 Shell. It responds with the same error messages. I also ran the python file from Terminal with the sudo permission and the same error messages appeared. The Python 3.4.2 Shell returned an "invalid syntax" error.

Comment: You can't run a shell script from the python interpreter :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have permission to run the `./Adafruit_DHT` command. Try changing the permissions on it. In a terminal in the directory with `Adafruit_DHT`, execute the following:

`chmod +x ./Adafruit_DHT`

and running it again.

More information on chmod and file permissions:
http://catcode.com/teachmod/chmod_cmd.html

Comment: I tried this. Unfortunately the same errors appeared. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: are you able to execute the command `./Adafruit_DHT` when you are in the correct folder? just type that in and get it to run?

Comment: I can now see temperature and humidity data in the terminal. TheAdafruit_DHT was removed and

Comment: Disregard above... I can now see temperature and humidity data in the terminal. The      ./Adafruit_DHT was changed to     ./AdafruitDHT.py (note the elimination of the _ and addition of .py. The plot.ly chart loads in my web browser automatically. Unfortunately the data does not appear. This code ran alright      python -c "import plotly; plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='DemoAccount', api_key='lr1c37zw81')"

Comment: which web browser are you using? If using chrome, can you try running the code again, and inspecting the browser console by hitting ctrl+shift+i and clicking on console.